# How does FD_ISSET work?

Tags: c, sockets

The man page says that FD_ISSET check whether the socket is in the set. So, I think that the condition `if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds))` should print out immediately if stdin is in set, but it actually waits until I hit enter. What do I miss here? is that true stdin has been **already set** when the program calls `FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds)`?

why if I enter other character rather than the enter key, the console returns command not found? I thought the character should be treated as any other character entered when I can fgets for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set readfds;

    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

    // don't care about writefds and exceptfds:
    select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds))
        printf("A key was pressed!\n");
    else
        printf("Timed out.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `select` to wait for? Note that this system call reuses the input sets for output.

Comment: so select blocks and only when I hit enter the condition is run?

Comment: Yes, I suspect `select` is what is doing the "waiting", not `FD_ISSET` (which is quite possibly a macro anyway, not a function call - but that may be different on different platforms/libraries/etc.).

Comment: @PMH: Well, yes, the waiting for I/O is the whole point of `select`. Wasn't that what you were trying to use it for in the first place?

Comment: @doynax: I am a newbie to networking programming. I cannot even remember that select would wait.

Comment: @PMH: To be clear `select` doesn't wait specifically for enter. Instead it is waiting for input on `STDIN` as you asked it to, and while in cooked mode the console buffers up and hands over whole lines at a time.

Comment: @doynax can you explain why if I don't enter any input, FD_ISSET would return false; the program print "time out". It seems to me that FD_ISSET check whether there is something to read from the stdin rather than whether the stdin is in the set. I say so because if I am not wrong, stdin, stdout, and stderr would be created when a program runs. So, I don't find a reason to see why stdin is not in the set after the program calls fd_set

Comment: @PMH: On input to `select` the read set specifies the _set_ of file descriptors to wait for, while on return hands back the sub-set of descriptors which have input available to read. If you wait for the time-out then there is nothing to be read on standard input, and so the flag will be clear.

Comment: OT: `unistd.h` already `#define`s `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: This program is from [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). "If you're on a line buffered terminal, the key you hit should be RETURN or it will time out anyway."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select will wait for an enter or timeout.
You feel FD_ISSET is waiting for enter because
the select timedout.

You will understand better if you check for retval

```
struct timeval tv; 
fd_set readfds;
int retval;

tv.tv_sec = 2;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;

FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

// don't care about writefds and exceptfds:
printf ("before select \n" );
retval = select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
printf ("after select \n" );

if (retval == -1) 
    perror("select()");
else if (retval > 0)
{
    //if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds));
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
}   
else
    printf("No data . timedout \n");
```

Comment: Can you confirm that all the file descriptors would be remove from the set when time-out?

Comment: yes. you just put another select before return , you will realize that it is cleared on timeout.